# what is exactly the content of 'zf' in MATLAB function filter

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I know that in order to filter large amount of data in chuncks, it it possible to use the function 'filter' with the appropriate filter coefficients, 
and pass the final conditions 'zf' to the next chunk as its initial conditions 'zi'.

I am confused.
what is exactly the content of 'zf'?

does it hold the last relevant input samples? (in pure FIR filter)
the last relevant ouput samples? (in IIR)
what does it hold when both last inputs and last outputs are relevant?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

In case we have a large set of data or we are short in memory the `zf` and `zi` options will come in handy.

For example we can divide our data in two parts, `x` and `newx`, and use the `filter` function like,

```
[y,zf] = filter(b,a,x);
newy = filter(b,a,newx,zf);
```

For a filter with `a` and `b` as in,

[image]

we will be referring back to `length(a) -1` samples of `y` and `length(b) -1` samples of `x`.

So for continuing our filter over the second half we will need `max(length(a),length(b)) -1` calls from the first half.

## Example 1

```
y[n] = x[n] + 2 * x[n-1] + 3 * x[n-2];
```

which is,

```
a = 1;
b = [1 2 3];
```

example input and output are,

```
x = [1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9];
y = [1     4    10    16    22    28    34    40    46];
zf = [42  27]';
```

Implementing the filter over `newx`, for first two samples we have,

```
newy[1] = newx[1] + 2*9 + 3*8 = newx[1] + 42 = newx[1] + zf[1];
newy[2] = newx[2] + 2 * newx[1] + 3*9 = newx[2] + 2 * newx[1] + zf[2];
```

## Example 2

```
x = 1 : 9;
b = [1 1 1];
a = [1 2];
[y,zf] = filter(b,a,x);
```

This corresponds to `y[n] = x[n] + x[n-1] + x[n-2] - 2*y[n-1]`.

The inputs and outputs are:

```
 x = [1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9];
 y = [1     1     4     1    10    -5    28   -35    94];
 zf = [-171 9]';
```

Now for the first value of second half:

```
newy[1] = newx[1] + 9 + 8 - 2 * 94 = newx[1] - 171 = newx[1] + zf(1);
newy[2] = newx[2] + newx[1] + 9 - 2*newy[1] = newx[2] + newx[1] + zf(2) - 2*newy[1];
```

So I think it's pretty obvious now, how `zf` works.

Comment: thank's a lot I really liked your answer and examples, but in the last case where  length(a) > 1 & length(b) > 1 , what is the specific content of zf?

Comment: @Day_Dreamer, Check the edit, It's much better now, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

The values in `zf` contain the internal state of the IIR filter. There are various ways how these filters are implemented in practice, but in all of them there are some delay elements, which pass some values to the next iteration.  See for example [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_filter#Filter_realization) of the wikipedia entry about digital filters. In the 'direct form 1', there are some delay elements to hold the last few inputs and and some other delay elements to hold the last few outputs. In the 'direct form 2', the delay elements contain some intermediate results. Independent of the exact implementation, these memory locations should be restored to not cause any glitches in the output when processing the data in chunks.

When processing data in chunks, you should use the function [`filter`](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) like this:

```
filter_state = []; % start with empty state

for i = 1:num_chunks
    input_chunk = get_chunk(i);
    [output_chunk, filter_state] = filter(b, a, input_chunk, filter_state);
    save_chunk(i, output_chunk)
end
```